# How to remove old versions of kernel-core and kernel from Red Hat Linux

Tags: redhat, fedora, dnf

But when I log into the server and run  `dnf list installed | grep kernel-core`, I get this response.

```
kernel-core.x86_64                            4.18.0-425.10.1.el8_7                  @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms

kernel-core.x86_64                            4.18.0-425.13.1.el8_7                  @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms

kernel-core.x86_64                            4.18.0-425.19.2.el8_7                  @rhel-8-baseos-rhui-rpms
```

Running `sudo dnf remove –duplicates` doesn't do anything. Running `sudo dnf upgrade` says everything is up to date.

How do I remove to old kernel-core and kernel packages?

OS Version

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
VERSION="8.7 (Ootpa)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="8.7"
PLATFORM_ID="platform:el8"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.7 (Ootpa)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:8::baseos"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
DOCUMENTATION_URL="https://access.redhat.com/documentation/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=8.7
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="8.7"
```

Edit:
the command `uname -r` returns: `4.18.0-425.13.1.el8_7.x86_64`
So it appears the newest version is not being used.

Answer (score 1):

To remove old versions of kernel-core and kernel from Red Hat Linux, you can follow these steps:

1. Check the currently installed kernel version using the following command:

```
uname -r
```

2. List all installed kernel packages using the following command. (This will display a list of all installed kernel packages, including the old versions.)

```
rpm -qa | grep kernel
```

3. Remove the old kernel packages using the following command:

```
sudo yum remove <kernel-package-name>
```

Replace  with the actual name of the kernel package you want to remove. For example:

```
sudo yum remove kernel-3.10.0-1160.el7.x86_64
```

Note that you should not remove the currently running kernel package.

4. If you have removed the kernel package for the currently running kernel, you should install a new kernel package before rebooting the system. You can do this using the following command:

```
sudo yum install kernel
```

This will install the latest available kernel package.

5. Once you have removed the old kernel packages and installed a new kernel package (if necessary), you can reboot the system to apply the changes.

```
sudo reboot
```

By following these steps, you can remove old versions of kernel-core and kernel from Red Hat Linux, which can help to free up disk space and improve system performance.

Comment: That works great! Also a coworker pointed out that I could use gubby as follows: 1) `grubby --info=ALL | grep ^kernel`, 2) `grubby --set-default "/boot/vmlinuz-4.18.0-425.19.2.el8_7.x86_64"`, and 3) `grubby --default-kernel` to check the current kernel after reboot. I'm unfamiliar with grubby. Are these both just two options to set the default kernel? (Also your method deletes the old version)

Comment: Also if you add back ticks "`" around blocks of code and numbered lists using "1)", it will make the formatting easier to read. Thanks!

Comment: This answer looks like it was generated by an AI (like ChatGPT), not by an actual human being. You should be aware that [posting AI-generated output is officially **BANNED** on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). If this answer was indeed generated by an AI, then I strongly suggest you delete it before you get yourself into even bigger trouble: **WE TAKE PLAGIARISM SERIOUSLY HERE.** Please read: [Why posting GPT and ChatGPT generated answers is not currently allowed](https://stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy).